# Insert into Django JsonField without pulling the content into memory

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, orm

Have a Django model

```
    class Employee(models.Model):
        data = models.JSONField(default=dict, blank=True)
```

This JSONField contains two year of data, like a ton of data.

```
    class DataQUery:

        def __init__(self, **kwargs):
            super(DataQUery, self).__init__()
            self.data = kwargs['data'] #is pulling the data in memory, 
           #that's what I want to avoid

            # Then We have dictionary call today to hold daily data
            today = dict()
            # ... putting stuff in today

            # Then insert it into data with today's date as key for that day
            self.data[f"{datetime.now().date()}"] = today

            # Then update the database
            Employee.objects.filter(id=1).update(data=self.data)
```

I want to insert into data column without pulling it into memory.

Yes, I could change `default=dict` to `default=list` and directly do

```
            Employee.objects.filter(id=1).update(data=today)
```

BUT I need today's DATE to identify the different days.

So if I don't need to pull the data column, I don't need kwargs dict. Let's say I don't init anything (so not pulling anything into memory), how can I update data column with a dictionary that's identified by today's date, such that after the update, the data column (JSONField) will look like {2021-08-10:{...}, 2021-08-11:{..}}

Comment: It is not clear to me what you aim to do. If you use `.update(...)` it will *not* load the data in memory that is in the database, but make a simple `UPDATE ...` query.

Comment: self.data = kwargs['data'] is pulling the data in memory, that's what I want to avoid

Comment: but `kwargs['data']` already a dictionary. The only thing that line does is copying a *reference* to an already existing item.

Comment: So if I don't need to pull the data column, I don't need kwargs dict. Let's say I don't init anything (so not pulling anything into memory), how can I update data column with a dictionary that's identified by today's date, such that after the update date field will look like {2021-08-10:{...}, 2021-08-11:{..}}

Comment: for a relational database, it makes more sense to work with an extra model with a `ForeignKey` to the employee. While relational database indeed have JSON fields, these are still more focused towards table join's than to JSONs. A JSON is therefore usually only used to work with *unstructured* data.

Comment: How will working with extra model look like, I don't get it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235885/discussion-between-field-boy-and-willem-van-onsem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For relational databases, one can store multiple items that belong to the same entity by creating a new model with a `ForeignKey` to that other model. This thus means that we implement this as:

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    # …
    pass

class EmployeePresence(models.Model):
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    data = models.JSONField(default=dict, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['employee', 'date']
```

In that case we thus want to add a new `EmployeePresence` object that relates to an `Employee` object `e`, we thus create a new one with:

```
EmployeePresence.objects.create(
    date='2021-08-11',
    data={'some': 'data', 'other': 'data'}
)
```

We can access all `EmployeePresence`s of a given `Employee` object `e` with:

```
e.employeepresence_set.all()
```

creating, updating, removing a single `EmployeePresence` record is thus simpler, and can be done efficiently through querying.